# Form - cannot select or high-light text in Field

Tags: html, css, forms

I am having this really weird issue where I cannot highlight my text in my form fields.

I cannot seem to figure out what the issue is, since everything but that seems to be working correctly.

I can't seem to understand where the problem lies - it doesn't work on Chrome or Safari.

```css
{
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  margin-bottom:-20px;
}
            
.outerForm img {
  width:800px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
            
form {
  display: table;
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  right:0px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  color:black;
  width:600px;;
  height:300px;
  margin-top: 100px;
}            
            
.innerForm > input, .innerForm > label {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-right: 5px;                
}
            
.innerForm > label {
  width:70px;
  text-align: left;
}
            
#messageLabel {

}            
            
input[type="text"] {
  width:200px;
  height:30px;
  border:none;
  outline:none;
  box-shadow: none;
  background-color:transparent;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
            
textarea {
  resize: vertical;
  width:85%;
  border:none;
  outline:none;
  box-shadow: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding-bottom: 18%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
            
textarea:focus {
  border:none;
  outline:none;
  background-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
            
.innerForm > h4 {
  margin-bottom:-10px;
  text-transform:none;
  font-family: 'Novecento sans wide';
}
        
input[type="text"]:focus, input[type="textarea"] {
  border:none;
  outline:none;
  background-color:transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-bottom:1px solid red;
}
        
#submitBtn {
  background-color:transparent;
  color:black;
  font-weight:400;
  border:none;
  outline:none;
  border:2px solid white;
  padding:10px 20px 10px 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top:15px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
        
#submitBtn:hover {
  background-color: #0080ff;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerForm">
  <img id="cardImage" class="img-responsive" src="PlayingCardTemplate.png"/>
  <form id="contactForm" action="Contact.php" method="POST">
    <div class="innerForm">
      <h4>Arshdeep Soni</h4>
      <label id="nameLabel" for="name">Name:</label>
      <input id="name" name="name" type="text"/>
      <label id="phoneLabel" for="phone">Phone:</label>
      <input id="phone" name="phone" type="text"/>
      <label id="emailLabel" for="email">Email:</label>
      <input id="email" name="email" type="text"/>
      <label id="occasionLabel" for="occasion">Occasion:</label>
      <input id="occasion" type="text" name="occasion"/>
      <label id="messageLabel" for="message">Message:</label>
      <textarea id="message" name="message" ></textarea>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitBtn" name="submit"/>
    </div>
    <p id="feedback"></p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: what are you trying to highlight? which css class for what element? can you be a bit more specific? I tried it jsfiddle, and as you enter certain field, black underline becomes red. So whats not working?

Comment: Just made it [here on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7vzcaz8f/) and it seems to work.

Comment: Same here, fiddled it - and it works (Chrome, Mac)

Comment: When i open the file on my localhost using Mamp - when a form has text within it - i cannot seem to highlight it and select or copy the text - it just wont highlight

Comment: Try to look for the ::selection inside your CSS maybe it is set to ::selection {background: transparent}; This can lead to this issue as it might be pre-defined if you are using an imported stylesheet or a theme

Comment: @Pyere - Perfect you were right - it was the ::selection in another stylesheet

Comment: I will post it as the answer:)

Answer (score 2):

Look for `::selection` inside the CSS Stylesheet.
An imported stylesheet or a theme might be include `::selection{background:transparent`
for multiple reasons.
looking for that class and editing it can be solve the issue.
Also you can add `color:` in order to color the text inside your selection.

For mozilla use `::-moz-selection`